# How to solve usage of anonymous function below 5.3 php version?

Tags: php

```
$total_amount=array_sum(array_map(function($item) { 
                            return $item['total_price']; 
                        }, $cartsItems));
```

This is my code which returns a total price in cart. I have installed a higher version on my local but the server is 5.2. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Have you looked at the manual for `array_map`?! First example and the answer is already there. Takes you probably less time than even reading this comment or writing this question here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function total_sum_of_cart($item){
    return $item['total_price'];
}
$total_amount=array_sum(array_map('total_sum_of_cart',$cartsItems));
```